# Angular 2 RC5 - common component used by different modules

Tags: angular

I have a component `LandingComponent` in a common library. This component needs to be used by almost all other modules in my application.

Files structure (inside `/app` folder):

```
/library
    landing.component.ts
/module1
    mod1.module.ts
    mod11.component.ts
/module2
    mod2.module.ts
    mod21.component.ts
app.module.ts
```

**mod11.component.ts** excerpt

```
@Component({
    template: '<landing title="M1C1 title" desc="M1C1 description"></landing>';
})
export class Mod11Component {}
```

**mod21.component.ts** excerpt

```
@Component({
    template: '<landing title="M2C1 title" desc="M2C1 description"></landing>';
})
export class Mod11Component {}
```

How should I organize imports and declarations/directives to have it working ?
Should I create module for library components and use it in other modules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

shared modules is the best solution you seek !